# How should I split grids in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I started learning grids in CSS. I thought that mimicking the main [Windows 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8) [Metro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_(design_language)) panel would be great exercise (my reference photo:
https://prnt.sc/orgusg).

I defined all of the panels and got them properly arranged. Here's some reference code showing what I've tried for template columns.

```css
.boxes {
    margin: 50px 150px;
    display: grid;

    /* 
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 2fr 2fr;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;  
        
        This is what I've tried here 
    */

    grid-auto-rows: 50%;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

For the first command of "grid-template-columns" I tried making all of the boxes that look wide span from their initial position (e.g., 1) to the position where they should look wide (e.g., 2).

```css
.mail {
    grid-column: 1/2;
}
```

For the second command of "grid-template-columns" I tried splitting the boxes.

```css
.ie {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}
```

But it gave me weird bugs.
My problem: I can't get the boxes to look different sizes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `grid-template-area` as suggested in [Kareem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456743/how-should-i-split-grids-in-css/57457420#57457420).

However, in this case I don't think it's a good solution, because it requires you to specify where every app goes in your grid. I don't actually think you want that. You want to be able to say "this box should take up N rows and N columns" and let the browser do that for you. This is actually easy to do.

If you have a grid element that should span two columns, you can do `grid-column: span 2`, or `grid-row: span 2` for rows. Or, of course, both, or a higher number.

By default, the browser will only put the elements in order. If a grid element won't fit in the next space, it will move to a new row and everything afterwards will be on that row. In this case, I don't think you want that, so you can do `grid-auto-flow: dense`, which will always put the content in the first available box, no matter what order they end up in. For example, here:

```css
.boxes {
  margin: 50px;
  height: max-content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.boxes>div {
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}

.mail {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.edge {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class=boxes>
  <div>Word</div>
  <div class=mail>Mail</div>
  <div class=edge>Edge</div>
  <div>Excel</div>
  <div>cmd</div>
  <div class=mail>Mail</div>
  <div>Solitaire</div>
</div>
```

Incidentally, the problem you were having in the first place is a fairly simple one. Your code says:

```
.mail{
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
```

The reason this comes up with a box that only uses one column is... because that's what `grid-column: 1/2` *means*! The numbers don't refer to the columns in the page, but to the lines that separate them. For example, look at this diagram:

```
1       2       3       4
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       |
```

You might think that `1/2` refers to filling up the first two columns: it doesn't. It refers to the first two *lines*: i.e. the first "column". Is this confusing? Perhaps. Now you know, it won't be!

Finally, I've also changed your `grid-template-columns` to `repeat(auto-fill, 100px)`. You don't know how wide the screen is, so why would you specifically want four columns? This code says "as many 100px columns as you can fit in the space provided".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid-template-area` property. This will make it much more easier for you:

Here is the [full description about CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

First: define your areas in `grid` container, something like:

```css
.grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-areas:
        "mail mail calender calender"
        "ie chrome message message"
        "store store store camera";
}
```

Each `""` contain one row. For the first row, we have four columns:

Mail: took 2 from 4 columns

Calender: took 2 from 4 columns

Now to make each div take it's actual position:

1. add the div in HTML

   ```html
   <div class="mail"></div>
   ```
2. For the CSS:

   ```css
   .mail {
     grid-area: mail;
   }
   ```

And so on.

Working Demo:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 700px;
  height: 525px;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "mail mail calender calender" "ie chrome message message" "store store store camera";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.mail {
  grid-area: mail;
  background-color: #0399AA;
}

.calender {
  grid-area: calender;
  background-color: #5B479C;
}

.ie {
  grid-area: ie;
  background-color: #4473B9;
}

.chrome {
  grid-area: chrome;
  background-color: #FFCD42
}

.message {
  grid-area: message;
  background-color: #963294
}

.store {
  grid-area: store;
  background-color: #099648
}

.camera {
  grid-area: camera;
  background-color: #B01D3A
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="mail"></div>
  <div class="calender"></div>
  <div class="ie"></div>
  <div class="chrome"></div>
  <div class="message"></div>
  <div class="store"></div>
  <div class="camera"></div>
</div>
```